# video editing software recommendation

Tags: video-editor, software-recommendation

I'm new in the field of video editing and I'm looking for software which can zoom any portion of video (*Magnifying  glass zoom*) as below.[image]

Suggest me some video editing software which is capable of doing that *except Corel video*.
I use 32 bit window 10

Answer (score 1):

The way this is usually done is either by recording the screen at full resolution and zooming out the footage until you want a close-up, or by using a screen recorder which allows you to zoom in as you're recording.

But if you already have footage, any decent editor should allow you to zoom in. Just know that zoomed-in footage will be at a lower quality than recording at the full resolution and cropping.

If you're on Windows, you can try Adobe Premiere or Sony Vegas. There are probably others, but those 2 are fairly popular.

Comment: Can u please enlist the recorders which are capable of doing this.